# How do I select a random view number in a CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm writing an application which reads data from an XML file and I use previous/next buttons to cycle through each record. However, I'd like to know how to use a button to select a random record. My Previous/Next buttons are as follows:

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)button.Tag;
        cvs.View.MoveCurrentToPrevious();

        if (cvs.View.IsCurrentBeforeFirst)
        {
            cvs.View.MoveCurrentToLast();
        }
}

private void Previous_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)button.Tag;
        cvs.View.MoveCurrentToNext();

        if (cvs.View.IsCurrentAfterLast)
        {
            cvs.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }
}

private void Random_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

I've searched everywhere for a solution, including Microsoft documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) but I'm still stumped. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
readonly Random _random = new Random();
private void Random_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)button.Tag;
    var view = cvs.View as CollectionView;
    if (view != null)
    {
        cvs.View.MoveCurrentToPosition(_random.Next(0, view.Count));
    }
}
```

All views in the default WPF classes not only implement [`ICollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) but should be subclasses of [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) which has a `Count` that can be used.

Comment: Thanks very much again H.B. It did baffle me as to why CollectionViewSource didn't have a `Count`. However, do you how to generate the next number, without it including the current number? I don't seem to be able to find a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: @duney: What do you mean by current number? The above code does not use a current number, it just specifies upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Sorry, that probably didn't make much sense. Well, the `CollectionView` number is set to the random number right? the problem I'm having is that sometimes when I press random, it will randomly select the same number as the index of the xml record that is currently shown on the screen, meaning that it doesn't change to a different record...just the same one.

Comment: @duney: Just create a field for the index that was randomly chosen and in which you save the random value and place a `while` loop around a random number generation which only moves on when a different number is generated. This is pretty basic stuff really...

Comment: I don't know why I didn't even think of that. Lack of experience I guess. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Random` is what you'll need to generate the random number, but you also need to figure out how many total records are in your `CollectionView` to get a range for the random number 
gen.

Something along these lines:

```
private void Random_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var count = CollectionView.Count;
    var random = new System.Random();
    var index = random.next(0, count);
    CollectionViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToPosition(index);
}
```

Comment: The upper bound of [`Random.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) is exclusive by the way, so `- 1` might not be such a good idea.